# Lync ActiveX stopped working , after changing the web application URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, active-directory

I use to have my web application on the server root, where the web application was accessible from the  following URL :- `http://servername.`

And the Lync ActiveX was working well . Then the client asked us to change the URL to have the following format `“www.companyname.intra”` instead of `http://servername`. So I added the required mapping inside the SharePoint alternative access mapping configuration, and the intranet became available from the new URL `www.companyname.intra`.

But I have noticed that the Lync ActiveX have stopped working after renaming the web application URL , while if I access the web application from the old URL the activeX will work well and it shows the user statuses. so can anyone advice what might be the problem ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new domain will be in a different Internet Explorer security zone. The first URL is the netbios name and will be treated as INTRANET. The FQDN will be treated as INTERNET if not configured otherwise. The security can be different for both zones. Try to add the new URL to the LOCAL INTRANET zone. Normally you should also see a popup for credentials. If this is not the case the default settings might have been changed and you have to look further.

Add to INTRANET ZONE: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303650

Comment: this what i did , i have defined the new URL "www.companyname.intra" to be for the intranet zone inside the alternative access mapping , while for the  default zone  i define "http://servername".

Comment: I'm talking about Internet Explorer zone not sharepoint aam. This is a client setting.